# mod_rewrite when a 404 occurs and a specific criteria hit?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am in a little over my head on a mod_rewrite. I need to:

1) Rewrite only when the URL matches a specific format as:
/provisioning/cfg010c6253d8f9.xml
The 12 character MAC address in the above example will always be different, but otherwise the URL will be the same format.

2) If it's a 404 response (not found).

Only then, do I want to rewrite as:
/provisioning/cfg000000000000.xml

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/provisioning/cfg000000000000.xml
RewriteCond %{CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 !-f
RewriteRule ^(provisioning/cfg[a-fA-F0-9]{12}\.xml)$ provisioning/cfg000000000000.xml
```

It goes in your root `.htaccess` file. If you would prefer to put it in your main config (recommended) then let me know and I will update the rule. This may need tweaking if `/provisioning/` is an alias. But otherwise should work fine.

Let me know any problems.